# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined using Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js, getstaticprops

I'm learning Nextjs. Getting this error while trying to fetch data from a firestore in dynamic pages ~ "[].js".

replace is a method used to transform the address prop in the EventLogistics component used below.

```
    import { getAllEvents, getEventById } from "../../../helpers/api-util.js"

function EventDetailPage(props) {
  const { event } = props;

  if (!event) {
    return (
      <ErrorAlert>
        <p>No event found</p>
      </ErrorAlert>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <EventSummary title={event.title} />
      <EventLogistics
        key={event.id}
        date={event.date}
        address={event.location}
        image={event.image}
        imageAlt={event.title}
      />
      <EventContent>
        <p>{event.description}</p>
      </EventContent>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const eventId = context.params.eventId;
  console.log(eventId);
  const event = await getEventById(eventId);
  return {
    props: {
      event: event,
    },
    revalidate: 3600,
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const events = await getAllEvents();
  const paths = events.map((event) => ({ params: { eventId: event.id } }));
  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
}
```

In api-util.js. I have few helper functions to fetch the data. Below is the code. kindly help

```
export async function getAllEvents() {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://next-events-4a68f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/events.json"
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  const events = [];
  for (const key in data) {
    events.push({
      id: key,
      ...data[key]
    });
  }
  return events;
}

export async function getFeaturedEvents() {
    const events = await getAllEvents();
  return events.filter((event) => event.isFeatured);
}

export async function getEventById(id) {
  const allEvents = await getAllEvents();
  return allEvents.filter((event) => event.id === id);
}`
```

Below is the code of EventLogistics component where the replace method is used on the props recieved

```
export default function EventLogistics(props) {
  const { date, address, image, imageAlt } = props;

  const humanReadableDate = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
  });
  const addressText = address.replace(', ', '\n');

  return (
    {/* renders a card with the props above */}
  );
}
```

TIA!

Comment: Put the code from your `EventLogistics` component, more specifically the part that calls the `.replace`

Comment: @Jorrmungandr I have edited the post and added what you had asked. Kindly take a look.

TIA

Comment: `event.location` seems to be `undefined` when you pass it to `EventLogistics`. Are you getting all the expected fields in your `event` object?

Comment: @juliomalves As far as I've understood, only the names of props-keys should be same between the parent and the child component. Isnt it?

Comment: I fixed my issue. Problem was in the api-utils.js file. Used .find instead of .filter in the getEventsById function

    export async function getEventById(id) {
    const allEvents = await getAllEvents();
    return allEvents.find((event) => event.id === id);
    }

It still used to fetch single event while using filter method, only the EventLogistics component wasnt accepting the props. Could anyone explain why?

@Jorrmungandr